Data cataloger for local file system and relational DBs
Currently have a situation where we have an amount of data that does not justify using Hadoop and HDFS, but would still like a local data cataloging solution like Apache Atlas for data cataloging and discovery in a nice web UI, but for a local file system (eg. a server of shared storage drives) that can also catalog relational DB data for DB instances running on the server or other servers.
Anyone know of such a thing? FOSS preferred, but not necessary.
